# Unexpected behaviour in a game example from a book

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml

I just got the book Head First C# 3rd Edition. In the first part of the book it gets you started creating a simple game where you make bouncing circles that you must avoid while clicking and dragging a "human" to safety. The coding involves C# as well as XAML for the graphics side. Everything works except for one thing. Instead of clicking and dragging the "human" if I click on it it will "follow" the cursor around and the game behaves as if the cursor itself is the human since that is where game over happens when I hit one of the bouncing circles. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I have looked over the code line by line next to the book.....The only thing I can figure out is that this block of code.

```
private void playArea_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (humanCaptured)
    {
        Point pointerPosition = e.GetCurrentPoint(null).Position;
        Point relativePosition = grid.TransformToVisual(playArea).TransformPoint(pointerPosition);
        if ((Math.Abs(relativePosition.X - Canvas.GetLeft(human)) > human.ActualWidth * 20)
            || (Math.Abs(relativePosition.Y - Canvas.GetTop(human)) > human.ActualHeight * 20))
        {
            humanCaptured = false;
            human.IsHitTestVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(human, relativePosition.X - human.ActualWidth / 2);
            Canvas.SetTop(human, relativePosition.Y - human.ActualHeight / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

The book says to put the human actual width and height to 3. But if I do that and try to click on the person in the actual game it won't even register the cursor at all. but if I put that at 20 or above and I click on the human as I said earlier it starts following my cursor around and the rest of the game behaves normally.

Here is the code that is supposed to make the cursor be able to "click" and "drag" the human.

```
private void human_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (enemyTimer.IsEnabled)
    {
        humanCaptured = true;
        human.IsHitTestVisible = false;
    }
}
```

And here is the related XAML code this is supposed to be working with to make it click and drag but instead is making it follow my cursor around the area:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="human" Orientation="Vertical" Canvas.Left="17" Canvas.Top="15" 
                    PointerPressed="human_PointerPressed" >
            <Ellipse Fill="White" Height="10" Stroke="White" Width="10"/>
            <Rectangle  Fill="White" Height="25" Stroke="White" Width="10"  />
        </StackPanel>
```

Everything else seems to be working right. I have checked the code in the book over and over and gone to their site. Nothing I did is different as far as I can tell. If anyone can help it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: when exactly will your StackPanel.PointerPressed get triggert?

Comment: It should trigger when I actually click on the "human". Which does trigger, but then then "human" object auto moves just to the right of the cursor and follows it around...and the "enemies" or "circles" will still trigger a game over if it hits my cursor, not the actual human object its supposed to interact with.

Comment: And to add. It is supposed to be I click and hold down and "drag" the human around. Not it auto-following like it is. And I don't know what in the code is making it do this. And the book has had me type it this way, and im so new to this I don't know what to look for since it wasn't a deliberate issue they put into the book.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the Book "[Head First C#, 3rd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449343503)"

I would say the problem isn't your code...

It's more about how he detects if a Human get captured, because he does not check if "`human`" collide with a "`enemy`" he just did some Pointerevent's which will get triggert if a Pointer (your Mouse) will enter an "`enemy`" and not if your "`human`" collide with him...

Comment: I understand that its recognizing the cursor as the actual target. The problem is that that happens when I click on the human object but the object itself then follows my cursor around...which then the game recognizes my cursor as the "human" object that if it collides with a circle or out of the area then it triggers the gameover.

Comment: your cursor isn't recognizes as human the problem is if your cursor collides (Entered) a enemy enemy.PointerEntered get triggered ... which is enemy.PointerEntered == "cursor" collide with a "enemy" and not like you want "human" collide with a "enemy"

Comment: Ok. Would that also be why the "human" object is simply following my cursor around instead of me being able to drag it? Or is this a separate but related problem?

Comment: mhh i think its because of your 20 in your playArea_PointerMoved() like the book sayed (page 43) if you change the value it will behave less sensitive but i'm not quite sure